# I have a form in lightning where the fields are retrieved from the fieldsets, now i need to have edit and save options in that

Tags: lightning-aura-components

component

```
<lightning:button onclick="{!c.saveForm}"
                          variant="bare"
                          label="Save"/>
```

controller.js

```
saveForm : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log('FieldSetcmpController.saveForm');

    var upsertRecordAction = cmp.get('c.upsertRecord');
    var record = cmp.get('v.record');

    if (!record.sobjectType) {
        record.sobjectType = cmp.get('v.sObjectName');
    }

    upsertRecordAction.setParams({
        recordToUpsert: record
    });

    upsertRecordAction.setCallback(this, 
        function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            console.log('FieldSetFormController upsertRecordAction callback');
            console.log("callback state: " + state);

            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");

            if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Success!",
                    "message": "The record has been upserted successfully.",
                    "type": "success"
                });

                toastEvent.fire();
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errorMessage = response.getError()[0].message;

                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Error",
                    "message": "The record was not saved. Error: " + errorMessage,
                    "type": "error"
                });

                toastEvent.fire();
            }
        }
    );
    $A.enqueueAction(upsertRecordAction);
}
```

Apex controller

@AuraEnabled
    public static void upsertRecord(SObject recordToUpsert) {
        upsert recordToUpsert;
    }

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to include the *relevant* portions of your code (we don't necessarily need to see everything), along with the specific issue you are struggling with and the complete text and location of any errors, in the body of your question. See [ask] for more about our expectations, and please [edit] your question to add information rather than posting comments.

Comment: Okay..Modified.Now i need to add save and edit functionality in cmp and controller.js ..I have tried with the record form in component but all the fields from the account object are displaying But i need to display only fields from the fieldset

Answer (score 0):

still you didn't mention where exactly you struck up. i didn't understand why you used  lightning:recordForm inside 
Lightning:recordeditform. i think you just need Lightning:recordeditform in your case if i understood correctly. please try below code. and please add your errors if you get

```
<aura:component controller="kalpita_123.FieldSetForn" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="fieldSetName" type="String" description="The api name of the field set to use from the given object." />
<aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String"/>

<aura:attribute name="fields" type="Object[]" access="global" />
 <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.init}" />

<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="test"
                          objectApiName="{! v.sObjectName }"
                          recordId="{! v.recordId }"
                          recordTypeId="{! v.recordTypeId }"
                          onsuccess="{!c.handleOnSuccess}"
                          onsubmit="{!c.handlesave}">
    <lightning:messages/>
    <aura:iteration items="{! v.fields }" var="field">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{! field.APIName }" class="slds-p-top_small slds-m-top_medium" />
    </aura:iteration>
<lightning:button class="slds-align_absolute-center" type="submit" label="Save" variant="brand"/>
</lightning:recordEditForm>    
</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
({   
 init: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log('FieldSetcmpController.init');

    var fieldSetName = cmp.get('v.fieldSetName');
    var sobjectName = cmp.get('v.sObjectName');
    var recordId = cmp.get('v.recordId');

    if (!fieldSetName) {
        console.log('The field set is required.');
        return;
    }

    var getFormAction = cmp.get('c.getForm');

    getFormAction.setParams({
        fieldSetName: fieldSetName,
        objectName: sobjectName,
        recordId: recordId
    });


    getFormAction.setCallback(this, 
        function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('FieldSetcmpController getFormAction callback');
            console.log("callback state: " + state);

            if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                var form = response.getReturnValue();
                cmp.set('v.fields', form.Fields);
            }
        }
    );
    $A.enqueueAction(getFormAction);
},
handlesave : function(cmp,event,helper){
 event.preventDefault();
var fields = event.getParam("fields");
cmp.find("test").submit(fields);
},
 handleSuccess: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.find('notifLib').showToast({
        "title": "Record updated!",
        "message": "The record "+ event.getParam("id") + " has been updated successfully.",
        "variant": "success"
    });
 }
```

})

still there is lot of options in lightning:recordform like onload,onerror please check
here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation

Comment: Thanks..but i dont want lightning:recordEditForm  as i want fields from the fieldset.I want custom edit..pls let me know how to do that

Comment: @PAashi , what you mean custom edit? can you please elaborate your use case

Comment: custom edit is nothing but our own logic for edit and save using fieldset

Comment: I have updated my save code where the fields from the fieldset should be saved..But its not working, any help @sdandamud1